# Background image size maintain its propotion

Tags: html, css

i have an image with 1400px by 400px and need to be fixed as background in my div.
The problem is i want to make background-image size maintain its proportions and fit in the div.

Here is my code, can you take a look at my code (link at the bottom) and help me to figure it out?

```
#pageheader{
 background: black url(http://s21.postimg.org/ml0zsve7p/test_image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed !important;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 1400px;
    overflow: hidden;


    -webkit-background-size: 100% !important;
    -moz-background-size: 100% !important;
    -o-background-size: 100% !important;
    background-size: 100% !important;   
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#textwrap {
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    background: white;
}

#textwrap h4 {
    color: #4c4d4e;
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: "GothamBook";
}

#textwrap p {
    color: #4c4d4e;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywt3N/1/)

Comment: usualy when you say `width:auto;` `height:[n]px;` the image keeps it's aspect ratio (or the other way around). it doesn't do that?

Comment: @myfunkyside - that post has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @myfunkyside i think you didn't understand what i ask, it just take 20sec to look at my link to understand that.

Comment: My deepest apologies, although I do still think this is something that has been asked many times before on here

Comment: You might not really want a background image at all... It's pretty hard to tell because your two examples are so different from each other. Are you building this mobile-first?

Answer (score 2):

You want the `background-size:cover;` option, which will make your image expand to cover the div while maintaining its proportions. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). This is supported in IE9 and up. If you want to support IE8 too, you can use [this polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e49PH/5/).

Edit: I think I understand the question now. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e49PH/9/).

Comment: If your div isn't going to change proportion, than this is what you want.

Comment: If `background-size:cover` should solve my issue, could you please update the jsfiddle for me?

Comment: @sheriffderek Yep, using px might work, but it depends on the exact size of his image and how the div can stretch (looks like his stretches horizontally but not vertically). ``cover`` is a simpler/more flexible option.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks man, but my background doesn't resize, and also is not fixed.

Comment: @ethan see the link below to understand what i need,
http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios/example-with-image

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/e49PH/6/**  ...and I can image this is what you want, but here, fixed: **http://jsfiddle.net/e49PH/7/**

Comment: @myfunkyside - what is going on buddy? Those fiddles are not correct... there isn't even an image... If you have an answer... Post an answer - and not a weird link filled comment.

Comment: @derek - They work for me, try changing the url of the background-image in the css.. Amir asked for an updated fiddle, so that's what I give him

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size
Seems you want `background-size:contain` or `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think your problem is not because of the css, but from the image url that redirected to the html page</strike> Just know that the url is different for each browser and each computer, so it shouldn't be your url problem. <strike>Try checking your image url first, and as</strike> For your css

```
-webkit-background-size: 100% !important;
-moz-background-size: 100% !important;
-o-background-size: 100% !important;
background-size: 100% !important;
```

it's better to remove the `!important`, because you don't have another css that change the background-size for id `pageheader`, and it's optional if you want to write

```
background-size: 100%;
```

or

```
background-size: cover;
```

and also remove `fixed` in your background

**Update**

try to copy this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywt3N/2/) to your html and try if it solved your issues

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the image to maintain aspect ratio like the second link you offer as example... then you can't be setting the height of the div as you have (400px)

Maybe you need to think about using an actual img tag and then use that element's natural shape to give the ratio to it's parent.

Step 1. Don't use bootstrap:

### HTML

```
<header class="container global-header">
    <div class="inner-w">
        
        <div class="image-w">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x400" alt="" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="your-text"> <!-- position:absolute; on top -->
            <p>Yo, this is some text... </p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</header>
```

Step 2. Make your own simple base styles and understand how they work - really really well.

### CSS

```
/* global */
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}


/* structural elements */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.container .inner-w {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}


/* basic responsive images */
.image-w img { /* (any image in a .image-w will fit the .image-w) */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


/* header */
.global-header {
    background-color: wheat;
}

.global-header .inner-w {
    padding: 0;
}

.global-header .your-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
}



/* main content */
.main-content {
    background: lightblue;
}

.main-content .inner-w {
    background: pink;
}
```

### js

You probably should serve different images with javascript based on window size and display type as well so you don't give a phone a huge image for no reason.  :)

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/zruIy

### otherwise

Here is how I would set the background image if you don't need it 100% exactly the same ratio at all times:

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Ywt3N/8/